# "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation" using POST request Ajax/NodeJs / MongoDB / Mongoose

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, mongodb

I am getting an error in the console when I try to do a POST request thought Ajax/Jquery.

This is the error:
[image]

The lines createTeam.js 67 and 31 are :

```
   $.ajax({   //line 67

   sendInvitation(teamID,_companyName,teamName) //line 31
```

the ajax request is inside the function sendInvitation. 
I call sendInvitation inside a success part of another ajax request:

```
 success: function(msg) {
                    $.cookie("teamID",msg.teamID)
                    $.cookie("sessionID",sessionID)
                    var teamID = msg.teamID;
                    sendInvitation(teamID,_companyName,teamName);
                    alert("team supposedly saved")
                }
```

This is sendInvitation function:

```
function sendInvitation(teamID, adminName,teamName){
        var emailList = [];
        $(".emails-ul").children("li").each(function(){
            emailList.push($(this).value);
        });
      $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:9000/email/"+teamID,
                dataType:'json',
                contentType: false,
                data:{
                    teamName: teamName,
                    adminName:adminName, 
                    emails: "argomes@lakeheadu.ca"
                },
                success: function(msg) {

                }
          });
}
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong. Does someone know?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with your contentType object. It's likely that jQuery doesn't know what to do with a content type of `false`. Either don't set your contentType or set it to the correct value, likely either `application/json` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Yes, Thank you for trying to help me.I do appreciate this. :)

Comment: If my answer was the solution to the problem, you should accept the answer.

Comment: Just after 2 days. It does not allow me now.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that condition. Glad to hear you found your solution! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution.

I  saw many questions about similar subject here answer.

Apparently, the Ajax request does not accept data as OBJECT.But I was not realizing that I was sending an object instead of a string. So in the calling of the function I was receiving an object in teamName (html object) and the  Post was not working.

So once I fixed that to a string, the Post worked perfectly.

This can be very useful to people that has the same problem.

Check if you are trying to send an object instead of a string or json. The request will not work with objects.

```
contentType: false,
```

ContentType is not necessary to achieve this.

Cheers. :)